# Checking whether specified multiple keys exist in Datastore table without fetching the entity

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-app-engine-python

I have let's say 1000 key names whose existance I want to check in the Google App Engine datastore, but without fetching the entities themselves. One of the reason, beside possible speedups, is that keys-only fetching is free (no cost).

`ndb.get_multi()` allows me to pass in the list of keys, but it will retrieve the entities. I need a function to do just that but without fetching the entities, but just `True` or `False` based whether the specified keys exist.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably use a keys-only query...:

```
q = EntityKind.query(EntityKind.key.IN(wanted_keys))
keys_present = set(q.iter(keys_only=True))
```

That gives you `keys_present` as a set of those keys in `wanted_keys` that **are** actually present in the datastore.  Not quite the same as your desired mapping from key to bool, but, the latter can be easily built:

```
key_there = {k: (k in keys_present) for k in wanted_keys}
```

...should you actually **want** it (a `dict` with `bool` values is usually more likely to be a less-wieldy hack for a `set`!-).

Comment: This solution will result in up to 1,000 individual queries as IN operator is just a shortcut for EQUAL for each member of the list. I suspect it can be very slow.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin, yes, I know how `IN` is implemented (it's pretty readable in ndb's source in the SDK, right?-) -- but, those many by-key underlying queries are as optimized as can be, and for big enough entities I'd bet on those plus the keys-only constraint to outperform any other approach (best is always to measure on **your own** entities & app of course!-).

Comment: I tried with 1513 keys: (1) With key.IN as above, takes 20 seconds. (2) With key.IN, but chunked to 100 keys and with fetch_async, takes 15 seconds. (3) With get_multi (not free), takes 4.6 seconds. Oh no!!!

Comment: This is a bad idea, as @AndreiVolgin said: You are firing as many queries as keys you have https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#neq_and_in

Comment: looks like you figured it out... there is no faster way than to just do **ndb.get_multi()**